# Why doesn't react.js recognize its own node.js module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, module, reference

I'm trying to do a hello world for react.js, and yet `react.js` fails on line `3`. The error is a reference error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module                     react.js:3
```

I take it that is a node module, and node just so happens to be what I am serving the `html` with. Not exactly sure why this is...Anybody care to wager a guess or clue me in? The code is pretty straight forward:

*main.js*

```
// main.js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('example');
);
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello React!</title>
        <script src="node_modules/react/react.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="example"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

node modules must not be included directly in an html file. they must be used through javascript files only. There is an exception when a node module provides a `dist` folder providing CSS & JavaScript to include in `index.html`. That is not the case for React node module. `react-dom` can be included as it is (coming from `dist` folder).

You already require react in `main.js`. there is no need to include it in `index.html`. When bundleling `main.js`, React will be included. If you don't bundle it, you must include a version of React that can be included in a html file. I think there is one in `node_modules\react\dist`

Comment: Thanks Damien Leroux